# pandas - change date formatting where input and output date format is known

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe for which I know the current date format, and also the final required date format.

example -
date_format_before_conversion = '%d/%m/%Y'
date_format_after_conversion = '%m/%d/%Y'

I want to read/parse the date as date_format_before_conversion and convert it to date_format_after_conversion.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['one', '13/1/2020'], ['two', '12/09/2019'], ['three', '11/02/2012'], ['four','1/13/2018']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sno', 'date_before']) 

#My intent is to read this as DD MM YYYY 

#print('Input Before formatting') 
#print(df) 

date_format_before_conversion = '%d/%m/%Y'


df['date_inter_mediate'] = df['date_before'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.strftime(date_format_before_conversion)
df['date_inter_month'] = df['date_inter_mediate'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.month
#print('\n\nintermediate After input formatting')
#print(df)

date_format_after_conversion = '%m/%d/%Y'
#df['date_MDY'] = df['date_DMY'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['date_after'] = df['date_inter_mediate'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.strftime(date_format_after_conversion)
df['date_after_month'] = df['date_after'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.month
print('\n\nOutput After formatting')
print(df)
```

If we look at sno 'four', should this not give an error? since as per DD MM YYYY format, 1/13/2018 is invalid date (month (13) out of range)! However, somehow it Automatically changes it MM DD YYYY, and take Month as 1. How can I enforce the error handling for this case?

```
Output After formatting
     sno date_before date_inter_mediate  date_inter_month  date_after  \
0    one   13/1/2020         13/01/2020                 1  01/13/2020   
1    two  12/09/2019         09/12/2019                 9  09/12/2019   
2  three  11/02/2012         02/11/2012                 2  02/11/2012   
3   four   1/13/2018         13/01/2018                 1  01/13/2018   

   date_after_month  
0                 1  
1                 9  
2                 2  
3                 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Note: My source data is pandas dataframe only, hence I cannot use read_csv's date_formatting parameters.

Comment: You can use `pd.to_datetime()` with `format` instead of `astype` :- `pd.to_datetime(df['date_before'],format=date_format_before_conversion)` which will throw an exception `ValueError: time data '1/13/2018' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)`

Comment: Also , If you want to `coerce` the invalid values and convert you can do `pd.to_datetime(df['date_before'],format=date_format_before_conversion,errors='coerce').dt.strftime(date_format_after_conversion)` which will convert the format from *`before`* to *`after`* leaving the invalid values as `NaT` which is null for datetime.Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: ah, looks like we hit upon the same solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arguments in `to_datetime` to help with this.
Example:

```
init_date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
final_date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

data = [['one', '13/1/2020'], ['two', '12/09/2019'], ['three', '11/02/2012'], ['four','1/13/2018']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sno', 'date_before'])     
df["formatted_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_before, format=init_date_format, errors="coerce").dt.strftime(final_date_format)
```

output:

```
     sno date_before formatted_date
0    one   13/1/2020     01/13/2020
1    two  12/09/2019     09/12/2019
2  three  11/02/2012     02/11/2012
3   four   1/13/2018            NaN
```

Documentation on the `errors` argument reads:

```
   errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
        - If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
        - If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
        - If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input.
```